# Spring Boot JUnit in Eclipse resulting in NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.addFilter

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, junit4

I'm unable to figure out what's wrong with my eclipse project here. I can run this JUnit Test case just fine using the mvn install command but when I try to run the JUnit Test case within eclipse (eclipse-java-mars-1-linux-gtk-x86_64 or spring-tool-suite-3.7.1.RELEASE-e4.5.1-linux-gtk-x86_64) it fails with the below errors. I tried a fresh checkout but the issue persists. Has anyone else hit this issue?

```
19:33:15.907 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.c.j.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner - SpringJUnit4ClassRunner constructor called with [class FilterTest]
19:33:15.925 [main] DEBUG o.s.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate from class [org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate]
19:33:15.935 [main] DEBUG o.s.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating BootstrapContext using constructor [public org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultBootstrapContext(java.lang.Class,org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate)]
19:33:15.948 [main] DEBUG o.s.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating TestContextBootstrapper for test class [FilterTest] from class [org.springframework.test.context.web.WebTestContextBootstrapper]
19:33:15.968 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.c.w.WebTestContextBootstrapper - Found explicit ContextLoader class [org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationContextLoader] for context configuration attributes [ContextConfigurationAttributes@6e6c3152 declaringClass = 'FilterTest', classes = '{class com.myapp.spring.Application}', locations = '{}', inheritLocations = true, initializers = '{}', inheritInitializers = true, name = [null], contextLoaderClass = 'org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationContextLoader']
19:33:15.974 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.c.support.ActiveProfilesUtils - Could not find an 'annotation declaring class' for annotation type [org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles] and class [FilterTest]
19:33:15.992 [main] INFO  o.s.t.c.w.WebTestContextBootstrapper - Using TestExecutionListeners: [org.springframework.boot.test.IntegrationTestPropertiesListener@78e67e0a, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@bd8db5a, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener@2f943d71, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener@80503, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener@4b553d26]
19:33:15.995 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved @ProfileValueSourceConfiguration [null] for test class [FilterTest]
19:33:15.995 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved ProfileValueSource type [class org.springframework.test.annotation.SystemProfileValueSource] for class [FilterTest]
19:33:16.021 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved @ProfileValueSourceConfiguration [null] for test class [FilterTest]
19:33:16.021 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved ProfileValueSource type [class org.springframework.test.annotation.SystemProfileValueSource] for class [FilterTest]
19:33:16.023 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved @ProfileValueSourceConfiguration [null] for test class [FilterTest]
19:33:16.023 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved ProfileValueSource type [class org.springframework.test.annotation.SystemProfileValueSource] for class [FilterTest]
19:33:16.024 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved @ProfileValueSourceConfiguration [null] for test class [FilterTest]
19:33:16.025 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved ProfileValueSource type [class org.springframework.test.annotation.SystemProfileValueSource] for class [FilterTest]
19:33:16.029 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved @ProfileValueSourceConfiguration [null] for test class [FilterTest]
19:33:16.030 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved ProfileValueSource type [class org.springframework.test.annotation.SystemProfileValueSource] for class [FilterTest]
19:33:16.033 [main] DEBUG o.s.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils - Getting field 'mergedContextConfiguration' from target object [[DefaultTestContext@cb51256 testClass = FilterTest, testInstance = FilterTest@59906517, testMethod = [null], testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [WebMergedContextConfiguration@5bfbf16f testClass = FilterTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.myapp.spring.Application}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', resourceBasePath = 'src/main/webapp', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationContextLoader', parent = [null]]]] or target class [class org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext]
19:33:16.035 [main] DEBUG o.s.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils - Setting field 'propertySourceProperties' of type [null] on target object [[WebMergedContextConfiguration@5bfbf16f testClass = FilterTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.myapp.spring.Application}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', resourceBasePath = 'src/main/webapp', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationContextLoader', parent = [null]]] or target class [class org.springframework.test.context.web.WebMergedContextConfiguration] to value [[Ljava.lang.String;@27f723]
19:33:16.035 [main] DEBUG o.s.t.c.s.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener - Performing dependency injection for test context [[DefaultTestContext@cb51256 testClass = FilterTest, testInstance = FilterTest@59906517, testMethod = [null], testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [WebMergedContextConfiguration@5bfbf16f testClass = FilterTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.myapp.spring.Application}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{server.port=0, org.springframework.boot.test.IntegrationTest=true}', resourceBasePath = 'src/main/webapp', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationContextLoader', parent = [null]]]].
19:33:16.121 [main] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
19:33:16.123 [main] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
19:33:16.123 [main] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Initialized StandardEnvironment with PropertySources [systemProperties,systemEnvironment]
19:33:16.124 [main] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding [integrationTest] PropertySource with search precedence immediately lower than [systemEnvironment]
2015-10-21 19:33:16.329  INFO 18277 --- [           main] o.e.j.i.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner    : Starting RemoteTestRunner on cdebergh-ThinkPad-T450s with PID 18277 (/opt/bin/eclipse/eclipse-java-mars-1-linux-gtk-x86_64/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/213/0/.cp started by cdebergh in /opt/source/sdk2/myapp-spring-microservice)
2015-10-21 19:33:16.356  INFO 18277 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@206a70ef: startup date [Wed Oct 21 19:33:16 PDT 2015]; root of context hierarchy
2015-10-21 19:33:16.562  INFO 18277 --- [           main] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2015-10-21 19:33:16.792  INFO 18277 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'encrypt.CONFIGURATION_PROPERTIES' of type [class org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.encrypt.KeyProperties] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2015-10-21 19:33:16.792  INFO 18277 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'encryptionBootstrapConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.encrypt.EncryptionBootstrapConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7b0d273a] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2015-10-21 19:33:16.999  INFO 18277 --- [           main] o.e.j.i.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner    : Started RemoteTestRunner in 0.822 seconds (JVM running for 1.757)

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.2.5.RELEASE)

2015-10-21 19:33:17.467 ERROR 18277 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Could not locate PropertySource: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8888/bootstrap/default":Connection refused; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
2015-10-21 19:33:17.481  INFO 18277 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@53de625d: startup date [Wed Oct 21 19:33:17 PDT 2015]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@206a70ef
2015-10-21 19:33:18.370  INFO 18277 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'beanNameViewResolver': replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.class]]
2015-10-21 19:33:18.632  INFO 18277 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.config.PropertiesFactoryBean     : Loading properties file from URL [jar:file:/home/cdebergh/.m2/repository/org/springframework/integration/spring-integration-core/4.1.4.RELEASE/spring-integration-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/META-INF/spring.integration.default.properties]
2015-10-21 19:33:18.636  INFO 18277 --- [           main] o.s.i.config.IntegrationRegistrar        : No bean named 'integrationHeaderChannelRegistry' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default DefaultHeaderChannelRegistry will be created.
2015-10-21 19:33:18.662  INFO 18277 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'infoEndpoint': replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointAutoConfiguration; factoryMethodName=infoEndpoint; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/EndpointAutoConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.RefreshAutoConfiguration$InfoEndpointRebinderConfiguration; factoryMethodName=infoEndpoint; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/autoconfigure/RefreshAutoConfiguration$InfoEndpointRebinderConfiguration.class]]
2015-10-21 19:33:18.909  INFO 18277 --- [           main] faultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor : No bean named 'errorChannel' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default PublishSubscribeChannel will be created.
2015-10-21 19:33:18.913  INFO 18277 --- [           main] faultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor : No bean named 'taskScheduler' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default ThreadPoolTaskScheduler will be created.
2015-10-21 19:33:18.923  INFO 18277 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=79168ac5-64ab-30e8-9544-e354fcb6d8c2
2015-10-21 19:33:18.932  INFO 18277 --- [           main] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2015-10-21 19:33:19.060  INFO 18277 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ba40fd01] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2015-10-21 19:33:19.071  INFO 18277 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'transactionAttributeSource' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2015-10-21 19:33:19.080  INFO 18277 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'transactionInterceptor' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2015-10-21 19:33:19.088  INFO 18277 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.BeanFactoryTransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2015-10-21 19:33:19.128  INFO 18277 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.config.PropertiesFactoryBean     : Loading properties file from URL [jar:file:/home/cdebergh/.m2/repository/org/springframework/integration/spring-integration-core/4.1.4.RELEASE/spring-integration-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/META-INF/spring.integration.default.properties]
2015-10-21 19:33:19.129  INFO 18277 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'integrationGlobalProperties' of type [class org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2015-10-21 19:33:19.129  INFO 18277 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'integrationGlobalProperties' of type [class java.util.Properties] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2015-10-21 19:33:19.135  INFO 18277 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'messageBuilderFactory' of type [class org.springframework.integration.support.DefaultMessageBuilderFactory] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2015-10-21 19:33:19.183  INFO 18277 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean '(inner bean)#1c758545' of type [class org.springframework.integration.channel.MessagePublishingErrorHandler] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2015-10-21 19:33:19.184  INFO 18277 --- [           main] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Initializing ExecutorService  'taskScheduler'
2015-10-21 19:33:19.185  INFO 18277 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'taskScheduler' of type [class org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2015-10-21 19:33:19.189  INFO 18277 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'integrationHeaderChannelRegistry' of type [class org.springframework.integration.channel.DefaultHeaderChannelRegistry] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2015-10-21 19:33:19.219  INFO 18277 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.RefreshAutoConfiguration$ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.RefreshAutoConfiguration$ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ab43ea17] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2015-10-21 19:33:19.602  INFO 18277 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 0 (http)
2015-10-21 19:33:19.927  INFO 18277 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2015-10-21 19:33:19.928  INFO 18277 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.23
2015-10-21 19:33:20.038  INFO 18277 --- [ost-startStop-1] .C.[.[.[/myapp/spring/service/v2] : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2015-10-21 19:33:20.040  INFO 18277 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2559 ms
2015-10-21 19:33:20.348  INFO 18277 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService  'metricsExecutor'
2015-10-21 19:33:20.687 ERROR 18277 --- [cat-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase   : A child container failed during start

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/myapp/spring/service/v2]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/myapp/spring/service/v2]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.addFilter(Ljava/lang/String;Ljavax/servlet/Filter;)Ljavax/servlet/FilterRegistration$Dynamic;
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean.onStartup(FilterRegistrationBean.java:257)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.selfInitialize(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:222)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.access$000(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:84)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext$1.onStartup(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:206)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter.onStartup(TomcatStarter.java:54)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5156)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 common frames omitted
```

...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.addServlet in Spring Boot while running a Spring MVC application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24080541/getting-nosuchmethoderror-javax-servlet-servletcontext-addservlet-in-spring-boo)

Comment: The difference here is that it's only happening when running the JUnit test in eclipse. It's working when running the pom via command line or even in eclipse via m2e.