# Getting NoSuchMethodError:javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()

Tags: java, servlets, tomcat8

I am facing an issue during deployment of a service in Tomcat 8. Getting following error :

> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()Ljava/lang/String;
>          at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsServerContainer.(WsServerContainer.java:149)
>          at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsSci.init(WsSci.java:131)
>          at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsSci.onStartup(WsSci.java:47)
>          at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5244)
>          at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>          ... 10 more

Method `getVirtualServerName` was introduced in Servlet 3.1  and after extracting `MANIFEST.MF` from my `servlet-api` jar I got following details :

```
Specification-Title: Java API for Servlets 
Specification-Version: 3.1 
Specification-Vendor: Sun Microsystems, Inc. 
Implementation-Title: javax.servlet
```

Which says that its having 3.1. So is there any other reason for this error? Please help

Comment: do you run from eclipse? or ... please let us know more about your environment, application, and settings.

Comment: Are you definitely using Tomcat 8? Your post is tagged 'tomcat7'...

Comment: @AndrewRegan Sorry it was a mistake. I edited. I am using tomcat 8

Comment: what I was thinking too, thats why I asked about the environment... do you use pom.xml ? maybe you should change the property to `<tomcat.version>`xxxx`</tomcat.version>` to tomcat 8... ?

Comment: @MrSimpleMind Yes I am using POM. But I have not declared `<tomcat.version>` . So if I dont declare what it will take by default ?

Comment: Is it spring solution? I think default it will run tomcat 7.. so if you want to run 8xxx.. then add that info.

Comment: @MrSimpleMind Yes . Its having Spring

Comment: You have twice written 1.3 where you mean 3.1.

Answer (score 27):

Check all your Maven (or equivalent) dependencies and make sure that you - or most likely another dependency - are not pulling in a pre-3.1 version of the `javax.servlet / servlet-api` that may be taking precedence over what's in your Tomcat 8. If you've manually deployed, make sure you haven't manually copied any servlet-api JARs into Tomcat itself.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26232535/954442

Comment: Locate the offending dependency which is bringing in the servlet-api jar in maven with the command mvn dependency:tree from the command line in the root of your project, search the output for the servlet-api its most likely 2.? version , exclude it from the dependency with the following in your pom.  { <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                </exclusion>}

Comment: @user1412523 Thanks! This solved it for me. My dependency was `google-oauth-client-jetty` I removed it as I did not need it anyway and it's working again.

Comment: my dependency was hadoop-common (2.9.2)

Comment: `mvn dependency:tree | grep servlet-api`

Comment: Thanks @user1412523, that was a really useful comment. I could finally get my apache fop-transcoder-allinone 2.4 dependency fixed and can move on now.

Comment: Here's another way to try to locate where the offending collision arises... run your build and either expand the war or find the folder that this was built in (target/xx in maven maybe) then locate the WEB-INF/lib folder and use this unix script to locate the jar files that contain classes with the name `ServletContext`.  You may get false positives, but it'll lead you in the right direction:
`find . -name "*.jar" -exec grep -l ServletContext {} \;`

Answer (score 22):

The method `getVirtualServerName` has been added in ServletContext in Servlet 3.1. See the java doc's method [getVirtualServerName](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getVirtualServerName--).

This problem has 3 primary causes:

1. Your servlet version is older than 3.1.
2. Some other jar has the servlet with a version older than 3.1.
3. Your tomcat version is older than 8

to solve it, you can try the below way.

I. Check your pom.xml for the code below.

```
  <dependency>
       <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
       <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
       <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

if your pom.xml has the above code, it would still has that problem. you can do the second way.

II. to check your other jar has refer to the `javax.servlet-api` jar. for example, the `org.apache.santuario` has refer to the `javax.servlet-api` jar. the pom.xml:

```
<dependency>  
    <groupId>org.apache.santuario</groupId>  
    <artifactId>xmlsec</artifactId>  
    <version>1.4.3</version>   
</dependency>
```

but when you look at the maven dependencies, it refer to the `javax.servlet-api` jar whose version is 2.3 older than 3.1.

[image]

so you should exclude the 2.3 version. pom.xml:

```
<!-- exclude servlet-api 2.3 jar-->  
<dependency>  
    <groupId>org.apache.santuario</groupId>  
    <artifactId>xmlsec</artifactId>  
    <version>1.4.3</version>  
    <exclusions>  
        <exclusion>  
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>  
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>  
        </exclusion>  
    </exclusions>  
</dependency>  

<!-- servlet-api 3.1 version has getVirtualServerName() -->  
<dependency>  
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>  
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>  
    <version>3.1.0</version>  
</dependency>
```

III. spring boot run the default tomcat 7. so define your tomcat version 8 instead of tomcat 7. so add the code your pom.xml:

```
   <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <tomcat.version>8.5.5</tomcat.version>
    </properties>
```

Comment: It is ok not to exclude transitive dependency, but just include the correct version. Maven takes the one which is closer in graph.

Answer (score 10):

I had this error on IntelliJ with maven after updating IntelliJ.

I could run the tests with maven but not from my IDE.

I solved the problem by removing the `./idea` and `project.iml` files and reloading the project.

Answer (score 5):

If you have used this dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-oauth-client-jetty</artifactId>
    <version>1.23.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Then please exclude as below:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-oauth-client-jetty</artifactId>
    <version>1.23.0</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Great that was exactly my error, how did you know that ??

Comment: @Rigoxls I remember I encountered this problem while I was working with Google  client APIs and Spring Framework

Answer (score 4):

Spring boot will run **tomcat 7** per default, you have to override maven build tomcat.version in your pom.xml. See below to run **tomcat 8.0.30**

```
<properties>
  <tomcat.version>8.0.30</tomcat.version>
</properties>
```

Should fix your problem.

Answer (score 2):

**Solved**
On my mac with java 8 was facing issue with downloaded tomcat from site and unzip.

My issue got solved because there was a extra servlet-api.jar file which was getting picked up. It was coming from 
/Library/Java/Extensions/servlet-api.jar

For finding it in your system you can use
sudo find / -name servlet-api.jar

Removed it by backing it up somewhere else.

I was following this for intallation
https://gist.github.com/ddanailov-nmdp/c97aba2ca926b9627f6b4f7174083a32

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this problem appears when you ran the application in Eclipse.
Use Dependency Hierarchy view to search for servlet-api in pom.xm

Answer (score 0):

After a huge pain & sifting through all these stackoverflow answers the only thing that ended up working for me was downgrading from tomcat8 to tomcat7. I know this isn't an ideal solution, and perhaps it was just a fresh install of tomcat that solved my problem. If all else fails give that a shot.

Answer (score 0):

I attach `gradle` style dependencies code.

```
dependencies {
    compileOnly("javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0")
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I  add vm option `-verbose:class` to find the wrong jar and
excluded the conflicted jar then add the higer version of javax.servlet-api(3.1.0), the problem was sovled.

Answer (score -1):

This surely has something to do with the version of javax.servlet and version of Tomcat.

In my case, it went away when I declared javax.servlet dependency in gradle with no version. Like this -

```
compile('javax.servlet:servlet-api')
```