# Unable to start component in tomcat

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, spring-boot

I am trying to run my spring boot microservice in eclipse. I do not have any server added in eclipse since spring boot runs on it's own server. But while starting the application I am getting the below error

```
 2018-03-26 16:21:10.625  INFO 11149 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.20
 2018-03-26 16:21:11.021 ERROR 11149 --- [cat-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase   : A child container failed during start
   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) [na:1.8.0_151]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) [na:1.8.0_151]
at  org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:939) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_151]
at      java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_151]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_151]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_151]
 Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component        [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]

  Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [Pipeline[StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5117) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.authenticator.NonLoginAuthenticator[]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.startInternal(StandardPipeline.java:182) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()Ljava/lang/String;
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.startInternal(AuthenticatorBase.java:1141) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]

 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
... 10 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Your error logs are not clear. Kindly upload complete logs

Comment: @Afridi updated..

Comment: This is the issue you are facing: "Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()Ljava/lang/String;"

So check these questions:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41603914/spring-boot-project-failing-with-nosuchmethoderror-javax-servlet-servletcontext?rq=1

Comment: or this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34950164/getting-nosuchmethoderrorjavax-servlet-servletcontext-getvirtualservername