# spring boot problem with tom cat ( Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]])

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I use spring boot v1.5.9.RELEASE

and this is the pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.dice-research</groupId>
    <artifactId>factcheck-service</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.4</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.dice-research</groupId>
        <artifactId>FactCheck</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </parent>
    <!--<parent> -->
    <!--<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> -->
    <!--<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId> -->
    <!--<version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version> -->
    <!--</parent> -->

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jdk.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdk.tools</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0_101</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.dice-research</groupId>
            <artifactId>factcheck-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>



    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>maven.aksw.internal</id>
            <name>University Leipzig, AKSW Maven2 Repository</name>
            <url>https://maven.aksw.org/archiva/repository/internal</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>maven.aksw.snapshots</id>
            <name>University Leipzig, AKSW Maven2 Repository</name>
            <url>https://maven.aksw.org/archiva/repository/snapshots</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>scala-tools.org</id>
            <name>Scala-tools Maven2 Repository</name>
            <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-tools/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>tc-maven-repo</id>
            <url>https://github.com/tc/tc-maven-repo/raw/master/releases</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>api.Application</mainClass>
                    <layout>ZIP</layout>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            

        </plugins>

    </build>
</project>
```

When I try to run it, I face this error

```
Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@798162bc: startup date [Fri May 14 21:35:54 CEST 2021]; root of context hierarchy
JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
Starting service [Tomcat]
Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.23
A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:939)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [Pipeline[StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5117)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.authenticator.NonLoginAuthenticator[]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.startInternal(StandardPipeline.java:182)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()Ljava/lang/String;
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.startInternal(AuthenticatorBase.java:1141)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 10 more
A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:939)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:367)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:99)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.<init>(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:84)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:554)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:179)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:164)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:134)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
        at api.Application.main(Application.java:15)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:948)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 6 more
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat


Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
Application startup failed
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:137)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
        at api.Application.main(Application.java:15)
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:123)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.<init>(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:84)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:554)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:179)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:164)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:134)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[-1]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:367)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:99)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Tomcat]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 15 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 17 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:948)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 19 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  12.917 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-05-14T21:35:56+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.3.4.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project factcheck-service: Application finished with exit code: 1 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Does anybody have an idea where could be the problem? I have no idea where could be the source of this problem. I try to change the spring web starter and spring boot version but they do not solve the issue.
thanks in advance for your time and your answer

Comment: You need to hunt down through the stack trace (thank you for including it!) and search for the INITIAL EXCEPTION: `Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()`  SUGGESTION: Look at the posts in these threads: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34950531/421195 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/47503644/421195

Comment: @paulsm4 thank you :) I find the conflict based on your guide