# Springboot: A child container failed during start java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException

Tags: maven, spring-boot

I have a SpringBoot application which works fine with IntelliJIdea, but from maven fails to start tomcat. Build works fine using maven.

Please help. I am using Java1.8.0_144. Apache Maven 3.5.0 and Spring boot 1.4.0.RELEASE.

This is the error stack trace

```
                24-11-2017 23:55:14.679 [Tomcat-startStop-1] ERROR o.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.log - A child container failed during start
                java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
                    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:911)
                    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:890)
                    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
                    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1403)
                    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393)
                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
                Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
                    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:158)
                    ... 6 common frames omitted
                Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [Pipeline[StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]]
                    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:158)
                    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5088)
                    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
                    ... 6 common frames omitted
                Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.authenticator.NonLoginAuthenticator[]]
                    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:158)
                    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.startInternal(StandardPipeline.java:170)
                    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
                    ... 8 common frames omitted
                Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()Ljava/lang/String;
                    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.startInternal(AuthenticatorBase.java:1085)
                    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
                    ... 10 common frames omitted
                24-11-2017 23:55:14.681 [main] ERROR o.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.log - A child container failed during start
                java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
                    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:911)
                    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
                    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
                    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
                    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
                    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:791)
                    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
                    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:356)
                    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:97)
                    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.<init>(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:83)
                    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:530)
                    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:176)
                    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:164)
                    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:134)
                    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:535)
                    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
                    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
                    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:369)
                    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313)
                    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185)
                    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174)
                    at com.intuit.qbdt.validation.Application.main(Application.java:20)
                    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
                    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
                    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
                    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
                    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
                    at org.springframework.boot.loader.WarLauncher.main(WarLauncher.java:59)
                Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
                    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:158)
                    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1403)
                    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393)
                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
                Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
                    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
                    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:890)
                    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
                    ... 6 common frames omitted
                24-11-2017 23:55:14.682 [main] WARN  o.s.b.c.e.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
                24-11-2017 23:55:14.697 [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication.reportFailure - Application startup failed
                org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
                    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:137)
                    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:535)
                    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
                    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
                    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:369)
                    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313)
                    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185)
                    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174)
                    at com.intuit.qbdt.validation.Application.main(Application.java:20)
                    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
                    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
                    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
                    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
                    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
                    at org.springframework.boot.loader.WarLauncher.main(WarLauncher.java:59)
                Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
                    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:116)
                    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.<init>(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:83)
                    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:530)
                    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:176)
                    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:164)
                    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:134)
                    ... 16 common frames omitted
                Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[-1]]
                    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:158)
                    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:356)
                    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:97)
                    ... 21 common frames omitted
                Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Tomcat]]
                    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:158)
                    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:791)
                    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
                    ... 23 common frames omitted
                Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat]]
                    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:158)
                    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
                    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
                    ... 25 common frames omitted
                Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
                    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
                    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
                    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
                    ... 27 common frames omitted
```

Here is the dependency tree

```
        mvn dependency:list -Dsort
        [INFO] Scanning for projects...
        [INFO] 
        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        [INFO] Building Account Validation Service 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        [INFO] 
        [INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:list (default-cli) @ account-validation ---
        [INFO] 
        [INFO] The following files have been resolved:
        [INFO]    ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.7:compile
        [INFO]    ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.7:compile
        [INFO]    com.beust:jcommander:jar:1.27:test
        [INFO]    com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.8.1:compile
        [INFO]    com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.8.1:compile
        [INFO]    com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.8.1:compile
        [INFO]    com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:jar:2.7.4:compile
        [INFO]    com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:jar:2.8.1:compile
        [INFO]    com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.1:compile
        [INFO]    com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:1.3.9:compile
        [INFO]    com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.7:compile
        [INFO]    com.google.guava:guava:jar:12.0:compile
        [INFO]    com.intuit.idps.mgmt.swagger:idps-mgmt-sdk-rest-io:jar:3.50.0:compile
        [INFO]    com.intuit.idps.swagger:idps-sdk-rest-io:jar:3.50.0:compile
        [INFO]    com.intuit.idps:idps-sdk:jar:3.50.0:compile
        [INFO]    com.intuit.platform.integration.hats.client:hats-client-common:jar:1.3.0.34:compile
        [INFO]    com.intuit.platform.integration.hats.client:hats-client:jar:1.3.0.34:compile
        [INFO]    com.intuit.platform.integration.hats:hats-common:jar:1.3.0.34:compile
        [INFO]    com.intuit.platform.integration.iam.client:iam-client-common:jar:1.0.0.30:compile
        [INFO]    com.intuit.platform.integration.iamticket.client:iamticket-client:jar:1.3.0.34:compile
        [INFO]    com.intuit.platform.integration.ius:ius-do:jar:1.45.0.9:compile
        [INFO]    com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.2.0:test
        [INFO]    com.netflix.archaius:archaius-core:jar:0.7.4:compile
        [INFO]    com.netflix.hystrix:hystrix-core:jar:1.5.3:compile
        [INFO]    com.netflix.hystrix:hystrix-javanica:jar:1.5.3:compile
        [INFO]    com.netflix.hystrix:hystrix-metrics-event-stream:jar:1.5.3:compile
        [INFO]    com.nimbusds:nimbus-jose-jwt:jar:2.26.1:compile
        [INFO]    com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:jar:2.4.0:compile
        [INFO]    com.squareup.okio:okio:jar:1.4.0:compile
        [INFO]    com.sun.mail:javax.mail:jar:1.5.5:compile
        [INFO]    com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal:resolver:jar:20050927:compile
        [INFO]    com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:jar:2.2.10-b140802.1033:compile
        [INFO]    com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.2.10-b140802.1033:compile
        [INFO]    com.sun.xml.fastinfoset:FastInfoset:jar:1.2.13:compile
        [INFO]    com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj:saaj-impl:jar:1.3.25:compile
        [INFO]    com.sun.xml.stream.buffer:streambuffer:jar:1.5.3:compile
        [INFO]    com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-rt:jar:2.2.10:compile
        [INFO]    com.sun.xml.ws:policy:jar:2.4:compile
        [INFO]    commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.10:compile
        [INFO]    commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2:compile
        [INFO]    commons-configuration:commons-configuration:jar:1.8:compile
        [INFO]    commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile
        [INFO]    commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
        [INFO]    commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.0.3:compile
        [INFO]    commons-net:commons-net:jar:3.3:compile
        [INFO]    io.netty:netty:jar:3.5.8.Final:compile
        [INFO]    io.reactivex:rxjava:jar:1.1.1:compile
        [INFO]    javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
        [INFO]    javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.2:compile
        [INFO]    javax.jws:jsr181-api:jar:1.0-MR1:compile
        [INFO]    javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
        [INFO]    javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.2.12-b140109.1041:compile
        [INFO]    javax.xml.soap:javax.xml.soap-api:jar:1.3.7:compile
        [INFO]    javax.xml.stream:stax-api:jar:1.0-2:compile
        [INFO]    javax.xml.ws:jaxws-api:jar:2.2.11:compile
        [INFO]    junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
        [INFO]    log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
        [INFO]    net.java.dev.jna:jna:jar:4.2.2:compile
        [INFO]    net.jcip:jcip-annotations:jar:1.0:compile
        [INFO]    net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.1:compile
        [INFO]    net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.2.1:compile
        [INFO]    org.apache.commons:commons-crypto-idps:jar:1.1.1:compile
        [INFO]    org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.4:compile
        [INFO]    org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.2:compile
        [INFO]    org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.5:compile
        [INFO]    org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:8.5.4:compile
        [INFO]    org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:8.5.4:compile
        [INFO]    org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:8.5.4:compile
        [INFO]    org.apache.xbean:xbean-spring:jar:3.14:compile
        [INFO]    org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.9:compile
        [INFO]    org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:2.5.0:test
        [INFO]    org.beanshell:bsh:jar:2.0b4:test
        [INFO]    org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:jar:1.47:compile
        [INFO]    org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.55:compile
        [INFO]    org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
        [INFO]    org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
        [INFO]    org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:3.1.1:compile
        [INFO]    org.codehaus.woodstox:woodstox-core-asl:jar:4.2.0:runtime
        [INFO]    org.glassfish.external:management-api:jar:3.0.0-b012:compile
        [INFO]    org.glassfish.gmbal:gmbal-api-only:jar:3.1.0-b001:compile
        [INFO]    org.glassfish.ha:ha-api:jar:3.1.9:compile
        [INFO]    org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
        [INFO]    org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
        [INFO]    org.hdrhistogram:HdrHistogram:jar:2.1.7:compile
        [INFO]    org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.2.4.Final:compile
        [INFO]    org.jasypt:jasypt:jar:1.9.2:compile
        [INFO]    org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.0.Final:compile
        [INFO]    org.json:json:jar:20140107:compile
        [INFO]    org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons.spring:jaxws-spring:jar:1.9:compile
        [INFO]    org.jvnet.mimepull:mimepull:jar:1.9.4:compile
        [INFO]    org.jvnet.staxex:stax-ex:jar:1.7.7:compile
        [INFO]    org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.10.19:test
        [INFO]    org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.1:test
        [INFO]    org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.4:compile
        [INFO]    org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.3.0:test
        [INFO]    org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.21:compile
        [INFO]    org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.21:compile
        [INFO]    org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.21:compile
        [INFO]    org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.21:compile
        [INFO]    org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.21:compile
        [INFO]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:jar:1.4.0.RELEASE:compile
        [INFO]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.4.0.RELEASE:compile
        [INFO]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor:jar:1.4.0.RELEASE:compile
        [INFO]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:jar:1.4.0.RELEASE:compile
        [INFO]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:1.4.0.RELEASE:compile
        [INFO]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail:jar:1.4.0.RELEASE:compile
        [INFO]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:1.4.0.RELEASE:test
        [INFO]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:1.4.0.RELEASE:compile
        [INFO]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.4.0.RELEASE:compile
        [INFO]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.4.0.RELEASE:compile
        [INFO]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:1.4.0.RELEASE:test
        [INFO]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:1.4.0.RELEASE:test
        [INFO]    org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.4.0.RELEASE:compile
        [INFO]    org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-commons:jar:1.1.1.RELEASE:compile
        [INFO]    org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-context:jar:1.1.1.RELEASE:compile
        [INFO]    org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-core:jar:1.1.5.RELEASE:compile
        [INFO]    org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-archaius:jar:1.1.5.RELEASE:compile
        [INFO]    org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-hystrix:jar:1.1.5.RELEASE:compile
        [INFO]    org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter:jar:1.1.1.RELEASE:compile
        [INFO]    org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:jar:4.1.1.RELEASE:compile
        [INFO]    org.springframework.security:spring-security-rsa:jar:1.0.1.RELEASE:compile
        [INFO]    org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-core:jar:2.3.0.RELEASE:compile
        [INFO]    org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-test:jar:2.1.4.RELEASE:compile
        [INFO]    org.springframework.ws:spring-xml:jar:2.1.4.RELEASE:compile
        [INFO]    org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.2.RELEASE:compile
        [INFO]    org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.2.RELEASE:compile
        [INFO]    org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:4.3.2.RELEASE:compile
        [INFO]    org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.2.RELEASE:compile
        [INFO]    org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.2.RELEASE:compile
        [INFO]    org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.3.2.RELEASE:compile
        [INFO]    org.springframework:spring-oxm:jar:4.3.2.RELEASE:compile
        [INFO]    org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.3.2.RELEASE:compile
        [INFO]    org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.3.2.RELEASE:compile
        [INFO]    org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.3.2.RELEASE:compile
        [INFO]    org.testng:testng:jar:6.8.13:test
        [INFO]    org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.17:runtime
        [INFO]    xmlunit:xmlunit:jar:1.1:compile
        [INFO] 
        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        [INFO] Total time: 1.895 s
        [INFO] Finished at: 2017-11-24T23:44:48+05:30
        [INFO] Final Memory: 28M/437M
```

Here is my POM

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
            <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

            <groupId>com.abc.abcd</groupId>  <!-- change if you fork/copy -->
            <artifactId>account-validation</artifactId>             <!-- change if you fork/copy -->
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <!--<packaging>${packaging.type}</packaging>-->
            <packaging>war</packaging>
            <inceptionYear>2017</inceptionYear>
            <description>

            </description>
            <url></url>


            <name>Account Validation Service</name>
            <parent>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
                <relativePath/>
            </parent>

            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                <!--<exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>-->
            </dependency>
                <!--<dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>-->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
                    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.intuit.idps</groupId>
                    <artifactId>idps-sdk</artifactId>
                    <version>3.50.0</version>
                </dependency>
                <!-- JAX-WS -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2.10</version>
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
                </dependency>
                <!-- Spring JAX-WS Integration -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons.spring</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxws-spring</artifactId>
                    <version>1.9</version>
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.intuit.platform.integration.iamticket.client</groupId>
                    <artifactId>iamticket-client</artifactId>
                    <version>1.3.0.34</version>
                    <!--<exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>  -->
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
                    <version>2.7.4</version>
                </dependency>
                <!-- Test dependencies -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
                    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
                    <version>6.8.13</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-ws-test</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-hystrix</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1.5.RELEASE</version>
                </dependency>
                <!--<dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-hystrix-dashboard</artifactId>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-hystrix-network-auditor-agent</artifactId>
                </dependency>-->

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
                    <optional>true</optional>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>

            <properties>
                <java.version>1.8</java.version>
                <!--<tomcat.version>7.0.52</tomcat.version>-->
            </properties>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <suiteXmlFiles>
                                <suiteXmlFile>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                            </suiteXmlFiles>
                            <detail>true</detail>
                            <failIfNoTests>true</failIfNoTests>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
            <pluginRepositories>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>spring-releases</id>
                    <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
                </pluginRepository>
            </pluginRepositories>
        </project>
```

Please suggest!

Comment: From the stacktrace I believe this is the relevant part:

    `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()Ljava/lang/String;`

This method has been added in servlet-api 3.1.

You have `<packaging>war</packaging>` defined. Are you trying to run with a standalone Tomcat? Does it support servlet-api 3.1 (aka. is it a higher than 8.x version)? Have you tried jar packaging (with embedded Tomcat)?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to start your spring boot project with tomcat. you should do the below way.

I. to change your project application like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {


    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(Application.class);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

    }
}
```

II. to change your pom.xml，import javax.servlet-api jar and exclude spring-boot-starter-tomcat jar like this:

```
< !-- exclude the spring-boot-starter-tomcat -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version> 
    </dependency>
```

if you have some question about [Getting NoSuchMethodError:javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34950164/getting-nosuchmethoderrorjavax-servlet-servletcontext-getvirtualservername/47503564#47503564)
, pls refer to it.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work. I am still getting same error while starting the springboot app from maven.

Comment: @Pretty could you please post your project url in the github?

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue and the exclusion worked for me:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

I also had to remove the `<scope>provided</scope>` from the tomcat dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
</dependency>
```