# Tomcat error trying to start springboot

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot

Hi so I developed a springboot application and it was working fine until I renamed the package, and then i started getting this error...I changed the package name back but it still won't work.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = TestController.class)
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = ImageController.class)
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}

pom.xml

    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>basicspringbootapp</groupId>
        <artifactId>bsba</artifactId>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <name>bsba Maven Webapp</name>
        <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
        </parent>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.openpnp</groupId>
                <artifactId>opencv</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.13-0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.gdata</groupId>
                <artifactId>core</artifactId>
                <version>1.47.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit2</groupId>
                <artifactId>retrofit</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.drewnoakes</groupId>
                <artifactId>metadata-extractor</artifactId>
                <version>2.11.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
                <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

        <properties>
            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        </properties>
        <build>
            <finalName>bsba</finalName>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </project>
```

Error:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) [na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) [na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:939) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]

.....

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.startInternal(AuthenticatorBase.java:1194) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.27.jar:8.5.27]
    ... 10 common frames omitted
```

There is a similar question here ([Getting NoSuchMethodError:javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34950164/getting-nosuchmethoderrorjavax-servlet-servletcontext-getvirtualservername)) but I've already tried these solutions...my servlet-api.jar is version 3.1.0, tomcat version is 9.

The project was running fine until I changed the package name which somehow caused this issue...

Comment: This isn't enough information to answer your question. The error you've posted is a generic error returned by the Tomcat process when it fails to start a container and contains zero information that could be used to help you. Please search your logs for other errors that are specifically related to your application, and add it to your post once you find one.

Comment: @Brian i've updated it with a more specific error...i dont know what it means...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting NoSuchMethodError:javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34950164/getting-nosuchmethoderrorjavax-servlet-servletcontext-getvirtualservername)

Comment: Try extending your Application class with org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer class, if you are deploying the war into tomcat and not using embedded tomcat

Comment: @Kenster I've already tried these solutions, my servlet-version is 3.1 and tomcat version 9...

Comment: Your Tomcat version isn’t 9. The stack trace shows that it’s 8.5.27.