# Spring app works locally but not on Azure

Tags: java, spring, maven, deployment, azure-web-app-service

I've got a problem with deploying my Maven application on the Azure web service.
Locally everything works alright, the pipeline's working, and app is deployed, however, whenever I try to see page content on azure websites the response is:

> :( Application Error
> If you are the application administrator, you can access the diagnostic resources.

Of course, I checked azure logs and that's what I've observed:

```
2021-05-15T00:41:28.568009808Z     at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar!/:2.4.4]
2021-05-15T00:41:28.568014108Z     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:769) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar!/:2.4.4]
2021-05-15T00:41:28.568018408Z     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar!/:2.4.4]
2021-05-15T00:41:28.568022608Z     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar!/:2.4.4]
2021-05-15T00:41:28.568026808Z     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar!/:2.4.4]
2021-05-15T00:41:28.568030908Z     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1313) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar!/:2.4.4]
2021-05-15T00:41:28.568035108Z     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar!/:2.4.4]
2021-05-15T00:41:28.568039208Z     at pl.agh.restaurant_project.RestaurantProjectApplication.main(RestaurantProjectApplication.java:10) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2021-05-15T00:41:28.568043408Z     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
2021-05-15T00:41:28.568047508Z     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
2021-05-15T00:41:28.568051708Z     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
2021-05-15T00:41:28.568059308Z     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
2021-05-15T00:41:28.568063808Z     at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2021-05-15T00:41:28.568068008Z     at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:107) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2021-05-15T00:41:28.568072408Z     at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2021-05-15T00:41:28.568076608Z     at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
2021-05-15T00:41:28.568080808Z Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
2021-05-15T00:41:28.568084908Z     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:928) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar!/:9.0.44]
2021-05-15T00:41:28.568089208Z     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:843) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar!/:9.0.44]
2021-05-15T00:41:28.568093408Z     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar!/:9.0.44]
2021-05-15T00:41:28.568097708Z     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar!/:9.0.44]
2021-05-15T00:41:28.568102008Z     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar!/:9.0.44]
2021-05-15T00:41:28.568106308Z     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
2021-05-15T00:41:28.568110508Z     at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar!/:9.0.44]
2021-05-15T00:41:28.568114908Z     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
2021-05-15T00:41:28.568119108Z     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar!/:9.0.44]
2021-05-15T00:41:28.568123508Z     ... 30 common frames omitted
2021-05-15T00:41:28.568127608Z Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [NonLoginAuthenticator[StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]]
2021-05-15T00:41:28.568144308Z     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
2021-05-15T00:41:28.568148508Z     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
2021-05-15T00:41:28.568164008Z     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar!/:9.0.44]
2021-05-15T00:41:28.568168308Z     ... 38 common frames omitted
2021-05-15T00:41:28.568172308Z Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [NonLoginAuthenticator[StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[]]]
2021-05-15T00:41:28.568180008Z     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar!/:9.0.44]
2021-05-15T00:41:28.568184908Z     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar!/:9.0.44]
2021-05-15T00:41:28.568189108Z     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.startInternal(StandardPipeline.java:176) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar!/:9.0.44]
2021-05-15T00:41:28.568193308Z     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar!/:9.0.44]
2021-05-15T00:41:28.568197508Z     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5094) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar!/:9.0.44]
2021-05-15T00:41:28.568201708Z     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar!/:9.0.44]
2021-05-15T00:41:28.568205908Z     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar!/:9.0.44]
2021-05-15T00:41:28.568210108Z     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar!/:9.0.44]
2021-05-15T00:41:28.568214408Z     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
2021-05-15T00:41:28.568218608Z     at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar!/:9.0.44]
2021-05-15T00:41:28.568222908Z     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
2021-05-15T00:41:28.568227108Z     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar!/:9.0.44]
2021-05-15T00:41:28.568231308Z     ... 38 common frames omitted
2021-05-15T00:41:28.568235308Z Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.lang.String javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()'
2021-05-15T00:41:28.568239508Z     at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.startInternal(AuthenticatorBase.java:1355) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar!/:9.0.44]
2021-05-15T00:41:28.568243808Z     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar!/:9.0.44]
2021-05-15T00:41:28.568260608Z     ... 48 common frames omitted
```

I had problems with servlets before, but with exclucions I was able to remove error below:

> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.lang.String javax.servlet.ServletContext.getVirtualServerName()'

The occurring of this problem is very confusing to me and honestly, I am out of ideas on how to fix this.

Below, I attach POM.xml and azure.yml:

```
azure.yml
name: Build and deploy JAR app to Azure Web App - thepierogi

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Set up Java version
      uses: actions/setup-java@v1
      with:
        java-version: '11'

    - name: Build with Maven
      run: mvn clean install

    - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
      with:
        name: java-app
        path: '${{ github.workspace }}/target/*.jar'

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
    - name: Download artifact from build job
      uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
      with:
        name: java-app

    - name: Deploy to Azure Web App
      id: deploy-to-webapp
      uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
      with:
        app-name: 'thepierogi'
        slot-name: 'production'
        publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AzureAppService_PublishProfile_af0b43cf31c64844acb8e748c96899db }}
        package: '*.jar'
```

```
POM.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>pl.agh</groupId>
    <artifactId>restaurant_project</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>restaurant_project</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>

            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.156</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>9.2.1.jre15</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.12.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context-support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.13.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.supercsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>super-csv</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seedstack.addons.io</groupId>
            <artifactId>io-supercsv</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.9.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34950164/getting-nosuchmethoderrorjavax-servlet-servletcontext-getvirtualservername

Comment: I've read this page before and I handled servlets, using exclusions, and right now the app is running normally, but only locally.

Comment: Does my answer useful to you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check application logs like below.

[image]

You will find you missing startup command. In logs, it will show you like below:

```
2021-05-16T16:07:34.95**Z No STARTUP_FILE available.
2021-05-16T16:07:34.95**Z No STARTUP_COMMAND defined.
2021-05-16T16:07:35.01**Z Made a local copy of the app and using APP_JAR_PATH=/local/site/wwwroot/app.jar
2021-05-16T16:07:35.01**Z Running command: java  -Dserver.port=80 -jar /local/site/wwwroot/app.jar
```

So you can add startup command to slove the issue.

[image]

## Offical doc:

[1. Deploying your app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-java?pivots=platform-linux#deploying-your-app)

**Related Blog**

[2. Deploying Helidon applications to Azure App Service](https://medium.com/microsoftazure/deploying-helidon-applications-to-azure-app-service-966dac9f14d4)

Comment: Yes, you located the source of my problem, but the next problem has appeared after that. The azure is unable to access jarfile /local/site/wwwroot/app.jar. Do you have any idea how to fix this one?

Comment: The path should be /home/site/wwwroot/app.jar .