# NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.addServlet(Ljava/lang/String;Ljavax/servlet/Servlet;)

Tags: spring, maven, servlets, spring-boot, nosuchmethoderror

I'm running a spring-boot project about api docs, but encountered a problem which has killed my days.

Here are my dependencies in pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.tsinghua.mathservice</groupId>
<artifactId>math</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>mathservice</name>
<description>math service</description>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>mvn-repo</id>
        <url>http://maven.nlpcn.org/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<parent>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
<version>1.2.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
      <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.ansj</groupId>
      <artifactId>ansj_seg</artifactId>
      <version>3.7.2</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>  
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>  
    <scope>provided</scope>  
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-staticdocs</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.jena</groupId>
    <artifactId>apache-jena-libs</artifactId>
    <type>pom</type>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <exclusions>
  <exclusion> 
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
  </exclusion>
  <exclusion> 
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
  </exclusion>
</exclusions> 
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
</dependency>

    <dependency>      
        <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>      
        <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>      
        <version>2.4</version>      
        <classifier>jdk15</classifier>      
    </dependency>  

</dependencies>  
    <build>
        <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin> 
        </plugins>
    </build>  
</project>
```

Here are my errors:

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.addServlet(Ljava/lang/String;Ljavax/servlet/Servlet;)Ljavax/servlet/ServletRegistration$Dynamic;
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:133)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:474)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
at com.tsinghua.common.App.main(App.java:37)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.addServlet(Ljava/lang/String;Ljavax/servlet/Servlet;)Ljavax/servlet/ServletRegistration$Dynamic;
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletRegistrationBean.onStartup(ServletRegistrationBean.java:171)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.selfInitialize(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:222)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.access$000(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:84)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext$1.onStartup(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:206)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.ServletContextInitializerConfiguration$Initializer.callInitializers(ServletContextInitializerConfiguration.java:96)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.ServletContextInitializerConfiguration$Initializer.doStart(ServletContextInitializerConfiguration.java:85)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:106)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.doStart(ScopedHandler.java:120)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:784)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:294)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1349)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1342)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:741)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:505)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:387)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:354)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(JettyEmbeddedServletContainer.java:83)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedServletContainer.<init>(JettyEmbeddedServletContainer.java:72)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getJettyEmbeddedServletContainer(JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:389)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:135)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:157)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:130)
... 12 more
```

I used the jdk1.8 but there was indeed no `addServlet()` in ServletContext.class, so I deleted `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/servlet-api.jar!` from my `/lib`, and I added `javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar`.
I ran again, the same error. But I found the `addServlet()` through the `step into` way:
[image]
[image]

I could not understand this. Why did it say "noSuchMethod"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.addServlet in Spring Boot while running a Spring MVC application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24080541/getting-nosuchmethoderror-javax-servlet-servletcontext-addservlet-in-spring-boo)

Comment: I have seen that and they are different. That answer explained the reason perfectly which I agree. But my servlet-api version is very new, 3.1.0. And I found the function `addServlet`, but it still implied `noSuchMethod`.

Comment: Maybe there is an other version as a dependency of one artifact. Show the dependency tree

Comment: omg your spring boot release is kind of ... old.  I would first update to the last  <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>

Comment: You should never put jars in the `.../jre/lib/ext/` directory unless you know exactly what you're doing. While there are perfectly valid use cases for placing jars there, the need to do so is very rare. You should empty this directory and rely upon your maven dependencies to provide the classes you need to build. The embedded Jetty runtime should provide the classes at runtime. As mentioned by @Georgesvanhoutte it seems like you have an old version that does not support `javax.servlet.ServletContext.addServlet`

Comment: @SteveC @Georgesvanhoutte Thank you so much. I have met so many errors which I don't know why and have wasted much time on. I just deleted jars in the `.../jre/lib/ext` and changed spring-boot version to 1.4.1. And they work!